# apt --fix-broken install gone crazy

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, dependencies, libraries

So recently I was trying to install an app which required newer version of [libpango](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libpango-1.0-0) and tried installing it using

> sudo dpkg -i libpango-1.0-0_1.50.4+ds-1_amd64.deb

Which gave me the following error

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpango-1.0-0:amd64:
> libpango-1.0-0:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.67.3); however:.
> Version of libglib2.0-0:amd64 on system is 2.64.6-1 ~ubuntu20.04.4.

Then I tried doing something any logical person would do, install libglib using the same method which gave me the error

> dpkg: error regarding libglib2.0-0_2.70.4-1_amd64.deb containing libglib2.0-0:amd64:
> libglib2.0-0:amd64 breaks gnome-keyring (<< 40.0-3~)

> dpkg: error processing archive libglib2.0-0_2.70.4-1_amd64.deb (--install):.
> installing libglib2.0-0:amd64 would break gnome-keyring, and reconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
> Errors were encountered while processing:
> libglib2.0-0_2.70.4-1amd64.deb

dependency of [libglib](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libglib2.0-0) which I tried installing from from apt (Big Mistake) which now shows apt unmet dependency the error is as follow:

```
sudo apt install scrcpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
scrcpy is already the newest version (1.12.1+ds-1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-pango-1.0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.50.4+ds-1 is to be installed
 libpango-1.0-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.67.3) but 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4 is to be installed
 libpangocairo-1.0-0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.50.4+ds-1 is to be installed
 libpangoft2-1.0-0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.50.4+ds-1 is to be installed
 libpangoxft-1.0-0 : Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.44.7-2ubuntu4) but 1.50.4+ds-1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and when I input

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

it goes completely crazy and asks to uninstall almost everything including GNOME desktop. Literally trying to nuke my complete system. Here is a list of all the programs it said to remove

```
adwaita-icon-theme apport-gtk apturl baobab brave-browser cheese chrome-gnome-shell cpupower-gui deja-dup eog evince evolution-data-server exo-utils file-roller gcr gdm3 gedit gir1.2-clutter-1.0
  gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-4 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-handy-0.0
  gir1.2-mutter-6 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gjs gkbd-capplet gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-calculator gnome-characters gnome-control-center gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-initial-setup gnome-keyring gnome-logs gnome-online-accounts gnome-power-manager
  gnome-screenshot gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons gnome-shell-extension-prefs
  gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-shell-extensions gnome-startup-applications gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-todo gnome-tweaks gnome-user-docs gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-gtk3
  gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-x gtk2-engines-murrine humanity-icon-theme ibus ibus-data ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 ibus-table indicator-application language-selector-gnome libamtk-5-0
  libappindicator3-1 libavcodec58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libchromaprint1 libclutter-1.0-0
  libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-pango20 libcolord-gtk1 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdv-bin libedataserverui-1.2-2 libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 libexo-2-0 libgail-common libgail18 libgarcon-1-0
  libgarcon-gtk3-1-0 libgcr-ui-3-1 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-desktop-3-19 libgnomekbd8 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgspell-1-2 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk3-perl libgtkmm-3.0-1v5
  libgtksourceview-4-0 libgweather-3-16 libhandy-0.0-0 libindicator3-7 libmutter-6-0 libnautilus-extension1a libnma0 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libpangoxft-1.0-0
  libpeas-1.0-0 libreoffice-gtk3 librhythmbox-core10 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libtepl-4-0 libthunarx-3-0 libtotem0 libvte-2.91-0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwnck-3-0 libxfce4ui-1-0 libxfce4ui-2-0 libyelp0
  mousetweaks mutter nautilus nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal nautilus-share network-manager-gnome network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome openjdk-16-jdk openjdk-16-jre orca pavucontrol
  pinentry-gnome3 pinentry-gtk2 plymouth-label plymouth-theme-spinner policykit-1-gnome python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets qt5-gtk-platformtheme rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar rhythmbox-plugins
  scrcpy seahorse shotwell simple-scan software-properties-gtk spice-vdagent sublime-text system-config-printer system-config-printer-common telegram-desktop thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support
  thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us totem totem-plugins touchegg transmission-gtk ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mono ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-session
  update-manager update-notifier usb-creator-gtk vino vlc vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-video-output xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xdg-user-dirs-gtk xfdesktop4 xfwm4 yaru-theme-gtk yelp zenity
```

Note: I tried installing libglib and follow the whole dependency thing manually but dpkg showed an error that updating libglib would break Gnome-keyring. Even If I could just clean that dependency error would be great!

Also I am extremely sorry, I think I wasn't supposed to install stable debian releases on its derivatives sorry about that. Good that I know about it but that might very well lead to requirement of a fresh install . I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: You should edit your question and include more complete details about the specific actions you took and commands you executed that led to these problems. It usually easy to determine a solution when you know what exactly caused the problem.

Comment: Now you will have to reinstall the operating system. If you need the latest version of all packages, then use a rolling release distribution (e.g. Arch, Manjaro or EndeavourOS) instead. Don't upgrade packages to newer version in Ubuntu/Debian. See [Don't make a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian)

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and Thanks for the help @guiverc and Archisman Panigrahi it appears that the reason this was happening was stupid me installed debian package in ubuntu thinking that it is th version that was mentioned in the application installation(Laverna). After removing the libpango which I installed from debian and then installing the ubuntu libpango build, everything was working again

Comment: You haven't provided your release still; `libpango-1.0-0 | 1.50.4+ds-1        | jammy           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` matches an off-topic release; ie. Ubuntu *jammy*.

Comment: I am really sorry about that @guiverc my bad, I am actually currently using ubuntu 20.04 and installed the libpango 1.0-0 1.50.4+ds-1 build instead of the libpango 1.0-0_1.44.7 which I was supposed to. This is what lead to such problems. After I downgraded the libpango library it was all back to normal again. Again Sorry about that, I am still a newbie in linux based OS(s), Thanks alot again !

Comment: Apt didn't 'go crazy'. It was trying its best to give you a consistent system based on the conflicting things you told it to do.

Comment: @Organic Marble I agree that it was completely my fault for this to occur but seeing the apt --fix-broken basically telling to nuke the entire system is really weird when the thing causing the problem is a package...